# How to Convert Zend_Db_Rable_Row to object

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

How to Convert Zend_Db_Rable_Row to object. Assume the database table has same column names as the variables in the object except the '*' (private variables in the object are starting with '*' (underscore))

for example database table column is username and variable name in the object is _username

Answer (score 1):

If your private variables are starting with an underscore you will most likely have getters and setters for these. E.g. `private $_myVar` will have setter `setMyVar()`. This code will call the right setter for each of the fields in the row:

```
public function convertToObject($row) 
{
    $myObject = new MyObject();

    foreach ($row->toArray() as $key=>$value) {
        // find out the name of the setter to call
        $setterName = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
        $myObject->$setterName($value);
    }

    return $myObject;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Zend_Db_Table_Row is an object. if you call fetchAll() it will return an array of Objects type Zend_Db_Table_Row (the column names are protected variables, accessed $row->column). If you call fetchRow() it will return a single Zend_Db_Table_Row object.

for example:

```
//assume we are working inside a Application_Model_DbTable_
public function fetch() {
$select = $this->select();
//here $result would return an array of Row objects that can be iterated over using a foreach
$result = $this->fetchAll($select);
//here we would return a single Row Object
$select->where('id = ?', $id);
$result = $this->fetchRow($select);
//you can call toArray() on these objects if you need an array
$array = $result->toArray();

}
//if you are using these objects in your application you can always access any of the
//columns using normal object syntax, without the underscores.
$id = $result->id;
$name = $result->name;
```

You may have some different behavior if you are using Zend_Db_Adapter or Zend_Db_Statement to make queries.

I hope I understood your question correctly.